# How to modify the PTE to point to another physical address (only modify the physical page frame number PFN in the PTE)

Tags: linux

I'm writing a Linux kernel module, and I'd like to modify the PTE to point to another physical address. It is worth noting that I require that only the physical page frame number PFN in the PTE be modified, and no other permission bits need to be modified.

The specific requirements are as follows:
The original PTE (PTE0) points to a physical address phys0. After modifying the PFN in PTE0 to the PFN corresponding to the target physical address phys1, it points to phys1.

I know that there are some macros in linux that can create pte (mk_pte). However, it changes the permission bits of PTE0 (I think so, please point out if it is incorrect).

How can I achieve the above goals?